# Effectively using the docs to find all standard library functions that take an io.Reader as an argument

Tags: go, code-documentation

I have a question about how to find information in the Go docs.

I saw that net/http Response.Body is a value of io.ReadCloser.

`go doc io readcloser` lead to `go doc io reader`, but that was a deadend.  I eventually learned I could read it with ioutil.ReadAll(rs.Body) through some duck.go searches.  How would I have figured that out **through the go docs**?

I guess my question **might** be: How could I find all functions in all packages that take an argument (r io.Reader)... like func ReadAll(r io.Reader) ([]byte, error) does?

Comment: There cannot be such a tool as "all packages" just is _too_ broad (e.g. your tool cannot know which of my private packages provide this). And even if you restrict to all "public" packages the amount would just be too large to be useful. The tools you are looking for are guru https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru and gopls https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gopls. Note that this question just vanishes after 6 weeks of Go.

Comment: changed the question to read "standard library functions"

Comment: Why do you want this? What possible value is there in knowing every function (even in the stdlib) that accepts an io.Reader?  What _actual_ problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am also wondering about the value of such feature, i.e. knowing every function that takes parameters of a certain type. Do you know of such feature from other languages and the corresponding tools?

Comment: I don't think the native doc server has a powerful enough search to do this. [You can use sourcegraph](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context:global+lang:Go+repo:%5Egithub%5C.com/golang/go%24+func%5C+%28%5C%28.*%5C%29%5C+%29%3F%5BA-Z%5D.*%5B%5E%5Cw%5Dio.Reader&patternType=regexp&case=yes), of course, but as you can see, the search results are of dubious value because there are just so many.

Comment: Rule of thumb: general uses of an interface declared in the standard library resides in the package where it is declared, or a very closely related package. Aside: io/ioutil is deprecated in Go 1.16. Use io.ReadAll instead.

Comment: @Peter thanks.  i've updated my golang to 1.16.

Comment: @Flimzy thanks for the reply.  My question is how do I learn to use the go docs as my primary source of information.  The original problem had to do with getting a response body from the httptest server, which I've already figured out.  Thanks for pointing to the 'guru' pakage - it looks neat.

Comment: Generally you look at the thing you're using to find out how to use it. If you're trying to figure out how to do something with the httptest server, look at the httptest docs.

Comment: maybe the question is not phrased correctly, but i think i understand the struggle of OP. I wish I could be more helpful, besides recommending reading the doc, view conferences online, and search in the source code. Below answer is really great.

Comment: Here is the go 1.16 link documenting the [deprecation of io/util](https://go.dev/doc/go1.16#ioutil) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This site [1] supports Regular Expressions, so you can do this:

```
case:y func\s[A-Z].+io.Reader[,)]
```

It's quite a lot of results, as `io.Reader` is arguably the most common interface value. Here are some results:

```
src/encoding/csv/reader.go
func NewReader(r io.Reader) *Reader {

src/testing/iotest/reader.go
func HalfReader(r io.Reader) io.Reader { return &halfReader{r} }
func OneByteReader(r io.Reader) io.Reader { return &oneByteReader{r} }

src/image/gif/reader.go
func Decode(r io.Reader) (image.Image, error) {
func DecodeAll(r io.Reader) (*GIF, error) {
func DecodeConfig(r io.Reader) (image.Config, error) {
```

1. https://cs.opensource.google/go